# Migrating from Angular6 to Vue

Tags: angular, vue.js, migration

I am new to Angular and have a reasonable knowledge of it.

i am planning to move to Vue due to excessive native definitions (directives,etc), referencing overheads, versioning pain-points and inconsistent behavior (atleast to what i have experienced) .

I have a project thats written in Angular6 and a few components have been written in Angular. I am planning to migrate from Angular to Vue. Is there a way i could create a Vue component library and use it within Angular project as i slowly migrate my components to Vue?
If not, can i route angular requests to a Vue created components server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

https://github.com/ngVue/ngVue

But unless you have a huge monolith of an application you would spend about twice the time and effort to implement this in the manner you described. I would simply try and rewrite it all at once if possible.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks.